# cant use flask library in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip, python-venv

im trying to run a simple webserver with python and flask
i created a python project and a virtual environment,
installed flask, but when im trying to run the script
it says " no module named flask"

here is my script :

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/ping")
def pong():
    return "<h1>PONG<h1>"


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>HELLO ! THIS IS THE HOME PAGE<h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and this is my terminal output :

```
(venv) shido@shido-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/Flask-Docker$ pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=3.6.0; python_version < "3.10" in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask) (4.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=3.6.0; python_version < "3.10"->flask) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.1.1)
(venv) shido@shido-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/Flask-Docker$ ./example2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

edit :
i succeeded running with the right venv.
but now it says :

```
from: can't read /var/mail/flask
./example2.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./example2.py: line 3: `app = Flask(__name__)'
```

edit 2 : done by switching from ./example2.py to python example2.py
can close question :) thanks martin !

Answer (score 1):

By running `./example2.py` your are executing your script with the Python interpreter specified in the shebang header: `#! /usr/bin/python3`

In order to use the Python interpreter of your virtual environment, activate your venv and run the following command:

```sh
(venv) shido@shido-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/Flask-Docker$ python example2.py
```

Comment: thanks ! indeed that was the problem with the venv.  
but now it says another error, i cant spot the syntax error and what is var/mail/flask

Comment: @MopyKing did you run you script like so `python example2.py` rather than `./example2.py` ?

Comment: you right ! i switched to python example2.py and it is running fine